# EMR Cluster "Error provisioning instances"

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

Trying to start EMR cluster following "Getting Started" documentation also tried ["Create a Cluster With Spark"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-launch.html), but the cluster creation stays 1 hour, 5 minutes in **"Starting"** status and then fails with:

- Terminated with errors Internal error
- Master Instance Group: Error provisioning instances
- Master - 1: Error provisioning instances

I tried different EMR releases *emr-5.9.0 - emr-5.6.0*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were trying to create EMR cluster in **EU (Ireland)** region and it was failing, when I changed region to **EU (Frankfurt)** it was created successfully. Don't know why, maybe AWS bug.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly use Amazon Linux AMI 2.0 which is currently not supported for EMR. Sadly, there is no log or useful error message after the provisioning.